# RDLC with Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I want to know whether Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition Update 4 comes with RDLC or not?

I installed Report Viewer Runtime 12 and Report Viewer 10 Redistributable Package still I don't see any option to add RDLC report to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2013/12/19/microsoft-visual-studio-2013-now-supported-for-rdlc-report-design.aspx) it doesn't support

> We are happy to announce that we have added support for using
>   Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (Professional, Premium, and Ultimate
>   editions) to create and modify RDLC reports. This lets you use the
>   latest version of Microsoft Visual Studio when designing reports for
>   Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2013 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 4` and I have no problem at all to create/modify `RDLC` report.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581432/missing-microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio/31582174#31582174) in order to use `RDLC` reports with `Community 2015` you have to install the `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools`: I think it is the same with `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 4`.