# How do I add reporting to my Visual Studio 2015 project panel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How do I add reporting to my Visual Studio 2015 project panel?

please understand by looking at below two images.

> [image]
> This is my Visual studio 2015
>
> [image]
> This is internet downloaded image

Comment: Is there even a question here? What are we supposed to "understand from these images"? They don't even have the same node expanded.

Comment: @Claies its not very well shown, but i *think* the problem is that in the second image you can see a "reporting" node, the former images does not have this.

Comment: Reporting project template is not available for Visual Studio community edition https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs.aspx

Comment: @JamesTrotter that may be true, but the first image is showing the Visual C# node, the second is showing a Visual Basic node.  Either way, I'm not sure that asking a question through screenshots is really acceptable.

Comment: Just found the category in my VS 2015 Enterprise, just *never* used it because I use SSDT BI. I suspect the OP is using Community edition

Comment: please look at the images care fully. There is no report in the first image. in the second image there is a report.
let me know how to add the reporting to the visual studio ?

Comment: @Claies i realise that, but in this instance reporting should show up on both, regardless.

Comment: @Claies. I'm Using do Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581432/missing-microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the resolution here:

[Missing Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581432/missing-microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio)

"The Report Designer is part of the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools.

You can add it using the Visual Studio setup (Programs and Features > Visual Studio 2015 > Change)"

Comment: Hi user874971, you might flag as duplicate if you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio 2015 do you have? In my version there is such option - **Reporting**. Screenshot to prove:

[image: New Project window]

Visual Studio version details:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
- Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
- Microsoft .NET Framework
- Version 4.6.00081

Comment: What reporting tools have you installed? What is this "Reports application"? The project category is *not* created by Visual Studio. Have you added any DevExpress, Telerik or other tools?

Comment: Nothing - it's just raw Visual Studio Professional. Check your edition, probably you have Express or Community.

Comment: Oops, found it. I've never used it because I typically use SSRS. Guess the OP is using Community

Comment: @Fka. I'm Using do Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 . But it is Not in my application reporting .

Comment: @Fka. i'm using same version of yours.

Comment: @RedAnz - that's odd. I've never installed anything additional to reporting projects. It was always out of the box.