# How to add Report in ASP.NET Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I have a problem on how to create a report in asp.net web application. When I right click on the project name and click add new item I can't see the "Report".

What I did is to add in the ToolBox the reportViewer webform but how can I use that If I'm not able to add a report in the project? any help will be appreciated.

I'm using visual studio 2010 express. If it's not available in that version, any suggestion on how can I create a report using reportviewer which is already in my ToolBox? or any approach to create a report? I can't use crystal/stimulsoft because they're not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you Add Report (RDLC), next you are supposed to Add DataSet. Bind this dataset to a database/table. Now Design your report in RLDC desinger. Lastly you are going to place RepowerViewer from Reporting Toolbox to view this report.

You can watch this [6 min youtube video](http://www.ytpak.com/watch?v=c-wup1EBkeI) which can very helpful

Comment: thanks , I understand your answer but the problem is I don't know how to add RDLC file in my project because I don't see "Report" in installed templates.

Comment: In your earlier version, you mentioned you could add it but you don't know what to do with it? Right click on Project > Add item > Make sure you select root Visual C+ category. Reports should be available, there. What do you see here? It is possible you dont have this template.

Comment: I could add the reportviewer but not the rdlc file.

Comment: can this link help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581432/missing-microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio