# Still no "Data Report" in VS2015 in Add New Item eventhough ReportsViewer is downloaded

Tags: vb.net, vb6, visual-studio-2015

As you can see am new to Visual Studio. I installed VS2015 community (by "default" installation). However, when I go search for the "Data Report" or "ReportViewer" as others may call it, I don't know where else to find it.

I've followed the steps I saw on the internet, including the `CTRL + ALT + D` But still, it didn't appear.
I've even tried to follow this step: [Download MS ReportViewer2015](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime/) yet afterwards no DataReport can be found on the toolbox or anywhere on the VS menu.

Compare to VB6 where DataReport is already part of its toolbox, I find it odd that VS2015: VB.NET doesn't have such feature by default. Can you guys help me solve this problem? Did any of you ever encounter it and then manage to get it fixed? I need some solution, the kind of which I don't have to uninstall the VS2015 since am afraid that it might affect my projects and would delete the `Solutions` and even the `forms`.

Your ideas are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Missing Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581432/missing-microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio). Please read all answers in this thread carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike past releases of Visual Studio, in Visual Studio 2015 the `ReportViewer` control requires the installation of *Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools* when setting up Visual Studio 2015 during installation

Comment: am currently in the middle of project making. How can I have these without reinstalling VS2015?
I've already downloaded the ReportViewer2015.Runtime in my VS, but the ReportViewer is still missing from the toolbox.
What to do? :'(

Comment: I just checked my control panels and it shows that I do have Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools installed... @Up All Night
Then why does Report Viewer isn't showing?