# Loading .rdlc report in Reportviewer manually in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, report, rdlc

I need a serious help in reportviewer.
I seen a lot links, tried a lot codes every way but cannot find a proper solution.
Please make me understand and clear my doubts even.
Totally confused which dataset to select during code and what is datasource.value thing which gives me error everytime...

I am showing the steps how I created the report and trying to make it work. This because I might have done any mistake in creating the reports and you people may catch it.

Now the problem is described below,
I have many .rdlc reporting my project.
What I done is

Note : Reportviewer containing form name is **Reports.vb**
RDLC reports are Reports1.rdlc,Report2.rdlc,...

1) Created Report like Add -> New Item -> Reporting -> Report -> Report1.rdlc
  Report Name: Report1.rdlc

2) Then I add dataset from here like this … 
[image]

3) DataSet properties opens, it even opens DataSource configuration Wizard.
I select stored procedures because I want to fetch data from my stored procedures and pressed Finish.
Here DataSet Name is **BonnyDataSet**

[image]

4) After that, I select data source from dataset properties… 
Now what is this Available datasets here in the last…??? 
And which dataset I have to consider during loading in ReportViewer???

[image]

5) Now I organised the column by adding the data columns from dataset1 shown below…

[image]

6) Now I added Reportviewer in form Reports.vb and tried a lot of codes….

Showing some of them here.

```
Private Sub Reports_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            'Select Case PubRepVar
            'Case "AccMast"
            Dim data As New BonnyDataSet
            Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("BonnyDataSet", data)
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds)   ‘------error here
            ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourProjectNamespace.Report1.rdlc"
            ReportViewer.RefreshReport()
            'End Select

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, My.Application.Info.Title, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I get the error as following:

> BC30311 : Value of type 'ReportDataSource' cannot be converted to
>   'ReportDataSource'

I have no Idea on this error.

Another code I tried is 
ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local

```
        Dim localReport As LocalReport
        localReport = ReportViewer.LocalReport ‘-------error here

        localReport.ReportEmbeddedResource =
            "ReportViewerIntro.Report1.rdlc"

        Dim dataset As New DataSet("BonnyDataSet")
```

Here error shows like :

> BC30311 :  Value of type 'LocalReport' cannot be converted to
>   'LocalReport'.

And I tried many other but can’t understand what the problem is.
Am I doing something wrong during the creation of .rdlc reports???

Needed help eagerly. Thanx

Comment: Have you tried `Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data)`

Comment: Also data should be result of `BonnyDataSet.AccMast_AllDetail`.

Comment: no, not happening, I tried this `Dim data = BonnyDataSet.AccMast_AllDetail` not working. Nothing working. It says **Value type ReportDataSource cannot be converted to ReportDataSource**... Now what's this ?? @RezaAghaei

Comment: What are namespaces which you Imported?

Comment: It seems you have a compile time error not a run time.

Comment: `Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` This is the only namespace I can see...
Yes It's compile time error... @RezaAghaei

Comment: And that's the main problem! You should use `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms`. Probably you are adding a wring dll too. You should have these references: `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.dll` and `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll`. Then `Import Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms` namespace.

Comment: Okay, so wait, shall I add these references into the project from Project -> Add reference??? @RezaAghaei

Comment: After putting a `ReportViewer` on a `Form`, those references will be added automatically, but if you have a `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForm.dll` remove it, also replace `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` with `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms` namespace.

Comment: Okay I did `Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms`... And where to check this `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.dll`??? @RezaAghaei

Comment: Wait, I am checking all the code again and reply you @RezaAghaei

Comment: There is still errors... At `Dim data = BonnydataSet.AccMast_AllDetail` it shows error as reference to non shared member required an object reference. 1 more thing, My dataset is `BonnyDataSet` and DataTable in it is `AccMast_AllDetail` but still I cant select `BonnyDataSet.AccMast_AllDetail`.. After `BonnyDataSet.` the intellisense shows me `AccMast_AllDetailDataTable`\`AccMast_AllDetailRow` etc..@RezaAghaei

Comment: When I select `Dim data = BonnydataSet.AccMast_AllDetailDataTable` it shows error **BonnydataSet.AccMast_AllDetailDataTable`** is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.@RezaAghaei

Comment: Surely it will throw exception, as I said  data should be result of `those data BonnyDataSet.AccMast_AllDetail`, create an instance of data set and then call `ds1.AccMast_AllDetail ` with parameters if it has any, it seem to be stored procedure. I can't test how it works, but get data using it and the use data. That's it.

Comment: Its done, I took instance of the dataset and done...
But 1 more problem I am facing, I am getting column names in report but not any datarows.... I checked my procedure and try to execute it in mssql server, I got data there.... Any Idea what am I missing??? @RezaAghaei

Comment: Check the result in application. How did you load data and how did you set it as Data source of report?

Comment: And Make an answer to your last comment, I'll upvote that...@RezaAghaei

Comment: I checked the result, I get many records there in sql management studio... I am posting that as a new question and sending you the email of the question link, this question solved so let not discuss here, moreover this question has a long discussion...@RezaAghaei

Comment: Good job, I'll see you'r last question and I'll share idea if I had any :)

Comment: Look into the answer and the way I loaded data. Maybe it solves the problem which you said in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider these notes:

1. You have a compoile-time error saying:

   > BC30311 : Value of type 'ReportDataSource' cannot be converted to
   >   'ReportDataSource'

   So you should check if you are using correct reference for `ReportDataSource` and using the class from correct namespace. A common problem is when you added `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.dll` as reference in a Windows Forms Project and added `Import Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms` namespace, so you will receive such exception.
2. After fixing that, you should pay attention the name of `DataSet` in your report should be the same name which you use when creating a new `ReportDataSource`. For example if the name of `DataSet` is `DataSet1`, you should use such code:

   ```
   Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", data)
   ```
3. The `data` which you want to pass to the report should be in the same structure which is used by report. For example, it should be an instance of a `DataTable`:

   ```
   TableAdapter1.Fill(Me.DataSet1, "Table1")
   Dim rds = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Me.DataSet1.Table1)
   ```
4. When setting which report you are using, use correct resource name. For example if you have a `Report1` in root of your project, and default namspace of your project is `YourProjectNamespace` then the resource name would be:

   ```
   ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "YourProjectNamespace.Report1.rdlc"
   ```

   When your report is in a folder, the folder name also will be added to its resource name.