# Add Horizontal Scrollbar for Panel

Tags: vb.net, panel, scrollbars

How i Can Add Horizontal  scrollbar for `panel` , i tried to make AutoScroll property to True , but this just show the vertical Scrollbar.

what i want is when the client minimize the `form` a Horizontal Scrollbar appear so he can see all the controls in `panel`, I'm using form without borders.

Maximize `Form :

[image: Maximize `Form]
Minimize 'form':

[image]

Comment: Look for Panel box settings. Go to properties -> look for scrollbar property check if the settings for scrollbar is not equal to none.

Comment: I already did, when i make autoscroll equal true, just the vertical scrollbar appears .

Comment: did you try "both"?

Comment: There is a possibility that horizontal bar will not show if the length of data inside the panel box is exact for ALL the data.

Comment: I didn't see anything for the scrollbar in the properties box other autoscroll, are you sure there is something else?

Comment: Try setting programmatically the panel box properties: panel.Autoscroll = True, panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = True, panel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = True

Comment: It's hard to answer this question because we don't know in what structure you have added controls to the form and what settings they are using. As some general rules when you need auto-scroll, you should not set dock for child controls, also parent should not be auto-sized, also it should set to be auto-scroll. This is not complicated but unfortunately we couldn't share more helps for this problem. I guess you will solve the problem if you pay attention to the container which you are using for childs, for example perhaps you have put controls on the panel not in it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei thank you to be here :)
I Tried many thing and nothing work, in this form Up i'm using `Form` and 3 Panels `panel 1` dock to Right side and `panel 2` for the border (i'm using the form without borders) and the last panel (`panel 3` ) fill dock the  remaining of `form` . , and i'm adding `usercontrol` in `Panel3`
which contain 2 panels `panel1` what i want to add scrollbar for it (horizontal) its dock up and the `panel2` is dock down.
and all panels is default I didn't change anything in properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting programmatically the panel box properties:

`panel.Autoscroll = True 
 panel.VerticalScroll.Visible = True
 panel.HorizontalScroll.Visible = True`

**Try adjusting your panel size then don't adjust the size of width of each data inside of it. I suppose it is because the data is EXACTLY fitted on your panel box.**

Comment: unfortunately this not working also, is there way to make alternative way to do it ?

Comment: Try adjusting your panel size then don't adjust the size of width of each data inside of it. I suppose it is because the data is EXACTLY fitted on your panel box.

Comment: Yes i did that last night and its worked now thank you , edit your answer to make it as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in the `Panel` properties. There you can see the `AutoScroll` property. The `AutoScroll` property:

> Indicates whether scroll bars automatically appear when the control contents are larger than its visible area.

BUT, if your data inside the `Panel` is EXACT, horizontal scroll bar or vertical scrollbar will not appear in your `Panel`.

Comment: is there way to make alternative way to do it ?

Comment: In the toolbox, there you can see the `HScrollBar` and `VScrollBar`. But you have to program it.

Comment: Do you know how ? Or can you give me a link to how to do it

Comment: Here: http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/horizontal-scrollbar-in-vb.net# and here http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/vertical-scrollbar-in-vb.net