# problem with rdlc in visual studio community 2022

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I have a problem when opening an rdlc file in visual studio community 2022, it opens only text, but it does not open the report. The report open in other PC in the school, but I have downloaded the things and it doesn't open, can someone help me?(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Thyr.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing Microsoft RDLC Report Designer in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581432/missing-microsoft-rdlc-report-designer-in-visual-studio)